# What is the ReadWriteTimeout alternative for HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, webrequest

I recently switched to `HttpClient` from `HttpWebRequest`, and it seems that `HttpClient` has only the normal timeout property. I can't find any property that represents the timeout of reading/writing. I can't find it in `HttpClient` or in `HttpClientHandler`.

Comment: Related post - [How exactly are timeouts handled by HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29851491/465053)

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the `HttpClient` class is to provide a higher level functionality, with the intention of making it easier to use. If you need a more granular functionality you need to use the lower level classes like `HttpWebRequest`.